# Find rows in dataframe which are aot available in another dataframe excludind one column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, have the same column names:

```
#df1
col_1    col_2    col_3
1        10        100
2        20        40
3        30        50
```

```
#df2
col_1    col_2    col_3
5        10        200
3        20        500
3        30        700
```

I want to compare those 2 dataframes based only on the col_1 and col_2 and find rows in df1 with values on col_1 and col_2 which are not present in df2

here's the desired output from the above example:

```
#df
col_1    col_2    col_3
3        30        50
```

I tried this code but it compare the whole row and I want to compare only the col_1 and col_2:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer',indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
```

Comment: "*I tried this code but it compare the whole row and I want to compare only the col_1 and col_2*"     put only those columns in merge then: `df1.merge(df2, on = ['col_1','col_2'], how = 'outer',indicator=True).loc....`

Answer (score 0):

Are the col_1, col_2 pairs unique in both DataFrames?

You can do:

```
join_cols = ['col_1', 'col_2']
merged = df1[join_cols].join(df2.set_index(join_cols), on=join_cols)
not_in_df2 = merged.col_3.isnull()
```

If the join index is unique then `not_in_df1` will be aligned with `df2`. Otherwise, you can do the following, which works in both cases

```
not_in_df2 = merged.index[not_in_df1].unique()
```

Finally,

```
df1.loc[not_in_df2]
```

EDIT:

Perhaps a better way:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.col_1, df2.col_2]).unique()
not_in_df2 = index.get_indexer([df1.col_1, df1.col_2]) == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Pandas's function `merge` I would suggest the next solution:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on = ['col_1', 'col_2'], suffixes=('', 'b'))
df = df.drop(df.columns.difference(df1.columns), axis = 1)
```

If not, here is a simpler solution to your problem:

```
df = df1.loc[np.where((df1["col_1"] == df2["col_1"])&(df1["col_2"] == df2["col_2"]), True, False)]
```

If you also want to reset the row numbers in the resulting dataframe you can simply use:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```